# Jquery Autocomplete : Enter key conflicts with another function

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a function which listens for the `enter` key press event on `textbox`  . If it is pressed , the function stops propogation of the event and then sends the contents of `command` to the server.

```
function(command)
{
          if(EnterIsPressed)
             {
                     event.stopPropogation();
                     command.sendToServer(); 
             }

}
```

The problem arises when I use `jquery autocomplete` in my code . Suppose I type something in the textbox and some autocomplete hints appear. I select one of the hint and hit enter. What I want to happen is for the `textbox` value to be replaced by the selected hint when I hit enter. And when I hit the next enter , the value should be sent to the server. But that's not happening. When I select the value and hit enter, the value is directly caught by the above function and sent to the server instead. Is there any way to handle this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution but an approach:

```
if(EnterIsPressed)
{
   if (textbox has some value) {
      event.stopPropogation();
      command.sendToServer(); 
   } else {
      //select the autosuggest value
      //fill the textbox with value
   }
}
```

Comment: This would work but when I type something in the textbox, it will always have some value irrespective of whether Ive chosen a hint or not. So the same problem again.

Comment: Thanks, it did help me. I used a flag instead but the approach was helpful.